# Angular 4 OAuth Security Localstorage

Tags: angular, oauth, token, angular-local-storage

i'm getting started with angular 4. Now i try an authentication with oauth. 
If the credentials are right, the server sends the token to the client.
Now i save it to the localstorage:
    `localStorage.setItem('currentUser', data.access_token);`

The authguard checks

```
 if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
```

Is this secure? Or are there further steps necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way but you have to do it the following way.

1. Get token when sessions starts / Login
2. Use token to secure routes
3. Use token for REST API / HTTP Methods
4. Delete token when session ended / Log out

Your approach is correct, the steps are just to mention everything, explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What happens if the user didn't really log out? The token is in the localstorage and the auth gard will pass the user. So where is the place to check if the token is expired?

Comment: Within the route you add method canActivate to verify token